# Escape ( ) % [ ] from string php

Tags: php, regex, string

With this code I can remove all special characters from string in php:

```
   function noSpeCha($string) {
     return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $string);
   }
```

But I need remove those characters too:

```
( ) % [ ]
```

I dont know how proceed.

Comment: where did you get the original regex? Have you read any of the regex documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`[^n]` is a regular expression pattern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) that matches characters **not** between the square braces (in this case it would match characters that are not `n`).

If you want change your existing regex to match `%`, `(`, `)`, `[`, and `]`, you'd need to remove them from the `[^...]` block (along with their [escape characters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)).

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $string);
                            ^^^^^  ^^^^^
```

####<sub>which leaves you with</sub>

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ \.&-]/s', '', $string);
```

####<sub>tidying things up a bit gives us...</sub>

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_ .&-]/si', '', $string);
```

Comment: There is no need to escape a dot `.` in a character class. It will match a literal dot and it won't match everything.

Comment: @HamZa, correct, I was just using this code to show the change needed to correct the regex for the change necessary. Backslash characters should also be escaped for use within the string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the exceptions from the list, this will only allow letters, numbers, underscores, dashes, and spaces:

```
function noSpeCha($string) {
  return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_- ]/s', '', $string);
}
```